# How to check if string starts with space in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a string which has a lot of spaces in it in the beginning.

```
my $str="       hello";
```

What is the condition to check if line starts with space?

Comment: What did your search of [the Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/) reveal to you?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) or [`ord`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html) for this. Keep it simple with

```
$str =~ /^ /
```

Better yet, the following checks if it starts with any whitespace characters:

```
$str =~ /^\s/
```

It's better to be correct and readable rather than the fastest.

Comment: You don't need "don't need" for this ;)

Comment: The point was readability. A simple regex like `^\s` should be very easy to understand, and work a lot better than `substr($str, 0, 1) eq " "` or `ord($str) == 32`

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `substr` *or* regular expressions for this!

```
ord($str) == 32
```

And, if you're doing a billion of these comparisons, you should notice a handsome performance increase as well:

```
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $str = "       hello";

cmpthese(0, {
    regex  => sub { $str =~ /^ / }, 
    substr => sub { substr($str, 0, 1) eq ' ' },
    ord    => sub { ord($str) == 32 },
});
```

Results:

```
             Rate  regex substr    ord
regex   6473675/s     --   -43%   -70%
substr 11300632/s    75%     --   -48%
ord    21653474/s   234%    92%     --
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't need regular expressions for this:

```
substr($str, 0, 1) eq " "
```